# How could i prevent for typing errors to make the bot error?

Tags: discord.js

This piece of code finds info about a skin you search out of a json file, my issue is if you write a mistake in the command then the bot errors. how would i prevent this from happening?

```js
if (msg.content.startsWith('LB skin')) {
    if (msg.author.bot) return; //just sum i do in all my commands to make sure it doesnt reply to itself
    var text = msg.content.slice(8, msg.content.length)
    if (!text) return msg.reply('Please give me a valid skin!');
    var info = database; //my json file
//what im asking is a piece of code that checks if it can be found inside of the JSON file


    let Name = Object.values(info.skins).find(
        (value) => value.name.toLowerCase() === text.toLowerCase()
       ).name//it cant find the skin because of a typo in the command itself and then it errors here
       let Tier = Object.values(info.skins).find(
        (value) => value.name.toLowerCase() === text.toLowerCase()
       ).tier
       let Weapons = Object.values(info.skins).find(
        (value) => value.name.toLowerCase() === text.toLowerCase()
       ).weapons
       let Event = Object.values(info.skins).find(
        (value) => value.name.toLowerCase() === text.toLowerCase()
       ).event
       let Game_version = Object.values(info.skins).find(
        (value) => value.name.toLowerCase() === text.toLowerCase()
       ).game_version
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle('Leak info:')
    .setAuthor('LeakBot#8631', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/779616585001861120/d8c6dd64ac92ec5ee5a1a893578722c3.png?size=256', 'https://www.paypal.com/paypalme/LeakBot')
    .setDescription(text)
    .addFields(
        { name: 'Name:', value: Name , inline: true },
        { name: 'Tier:', value: Tier, inline: true },
        { name: 'Weapons:', value: Weapons, inline: true },
        { name: 'Event:', value: Event, inline: true },
        { name: 'Game version:', value: Game_version, inline: true },
        { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B', inline: true },
    )
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('Created by pitched_mobile', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/539804475150434314/e22de33df46a9022b41817bfb732c9b3.jpg')
    msg.channel.send(embed)
}
```

Comment: Use typescript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright i found it. the code below checks if its inside of the JSON file

```js
    let test = Object.values(info.skins).find((value) => value.name.toLowerCase() === text.toLowerCase())
    if (!test) return msg.reply('Please give me a valid skin!');
```